# Trying to get property of non-object error handling

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

most of the rss have an property call content:encoded, so I get it using this

```
//in a loop {
$item_content=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

but I also experienced error with some blogs that in its rss it doesn't have content:encoded property so I got an error of Trying to get property of non-object. How to I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->length` property of the `DOMNodelist` before pointing out on that item:

```
$item_content = '';
if($x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->length > 0) { // if it exists, or at least one
    $item_content = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```